# Generate a fibonacci series with no loops or flow control in APL

Tags: fibonacci, apl

Is there a way to create a fibonacci sequence in APL with a one-liner that doesn't require loops or flow control?

I've done it with a function using `→` and a conditional test, but I feel there must be a more elegant, declarative way. An [example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#APL) that I've found that claims to do it on one line doesn't work on gnu-apl - it seems it's on the right track, using matrix math, but I'm having a hard time following along, and can't tweak it to work correctly.

I'm pursuing APL as my first real programming language (I love the symbols. I just do.) I'm now using Project Euler as a way to become better acquainted.

Comment: Why does it not work on GNU-APL? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Baqer Mamouri -  ↑0 1↓↑+/.×/N⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0  where N is 10 returns "1"

Comment: ↑0 1↓↑+.×/N/⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0 gives me the Nth fibonacci number in Dyalog APL (with []ML 3).  I can "animate" this line of code by making it a Dfn, i.e.{↑0 1↓↑+.×/⍵/⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0 }¨⍳20.  Note this works in []IO 1.  The each operator is effectively iterating the expression over 1, 2, ... 20.

Comment: Try 1,↑¨+.×\N⍴⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0 Origin independent

Comment: Both examples also work in NGN APL, http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/index.html

Comment: I'm responsible for the example that you link to.

The task there was to generate the Nth number. You're asking about the whole sequence. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: In general you can replace reduce `/` with scan `\\` to get a sequence of partial "sums", as @Lobachevsky shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love APL's symbols too, as well as its array programming power. Other array languages may be more powerful, such as J, but they lack the beauty of APL's symbols and explicit syntax.

I just tried the example you link to in GNU APL and it works all right:

```
      ↑0 1↓↑+.×/5/⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0
5
      ↑0 1↓↑+.×/6/⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0
8
      ↑0 1↓↑+.×/7/⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0
13
```

If you can't get it to work, make sure to:

- type (or copy and paste) the exact symbols shown in the example: in particular `×` is U+00D7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN, not an X; `⍴` is U+2374 APL FUNCTIONAL SYMBOL RHO, not any other Greek Rho, and definitely not a P; `⊂` is U+2282 SUBSET OF; and so on;
- test some numbers other that 1 or 5, because they are the only numbers that are equal to their Fibonacci number;
- if you are not putting an actual number in place of N, make sure you define N in a proper way, such as `N←7` by itself in a previous line.

If you still can't get it to work, type the formula one step at a time, starting from the right:

```
      2 2⍴1 1 1 0
1 1
1 0
      ⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0
 1 1 
 1 0 
      7/⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0
 1 1   1 1   1 1   1 1   1 1   1 1   1 1 
 1 0   1 0   1 0   1 0   1 0   1 0   1 0 
      +.×/7/⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0
 21 13 
 13  8 
      ↑+.×/7/⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0
21 13
13  8
      0 1↓↑+.×/7/⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0
13
 8
      ↑0 1↓↑+.×/7/⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0
13
```

As for the question title, I think this matrix formula nails it (bravo @mappo!)

If I were [golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), I'd probably use a shorter variation, but that's all:

```
      2⌷∊+.×/7/⊂∘.∨⍨1 0
13
```

There, from 24 to 17 chars. See if you can figure it out :-)

GNU APL is ok, although it lacks some modern features, but keep a copy of Dyalog APL Programmer's Guide & Language Reference handy, because it's one of the most comprehensive references about the language.

Comment: The problem was a dumb typo - I used +/ when I wanted just +. Breaking down how this works is very helpful, tho! I have a Mac, and can't be bothered to run an emulator just for this (and the MicroAPL download link appears broken...)

Comment: (Errr, by "this" I meant "Dyalog")

Comment: I use [Wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/) (a GUI for Wine) to run Windows apps on the Mac without running an entire Windows OS. The freeware / nagware version of Dialog works pretty well, as do many other utilities.

Comment: @Tobia: Just FYI, Dyalog released a version native to Mac but it requires a student (free) or full license.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this would be using the (relatively new) power operator.  This may or may not yet be supported by GNU APL, it works with Dyalog (I'm using 13.1) and NGN APL.

Try

```
 ({⍵,+/¯2↑⍵} ⍣ 20) (1 1)
```

Like the other examples, the iteration is hidden, here with the power operator.

The expression

```
({⍵,+/¯2↑⍵} ⍣ 3) (1 1)
```

is doing

```
{⍵,+/¯2↑⍵} {⍵,+/¯2↑⍵} {⍵,+/¯2↑⍵} 1 1
```

under the covers.

1 1 is the seed value and every successive {⍵,+/¯2↑⍵} simply catenates the sum of the last two elements.

Comment: No umlauted star in Gnu APL, alack. I've been following your other APL answers, tho! It's a very cool way of programming, and I'm happy to see there's a community of APL oddballs active on SE!

Comment: @RISwampYankee GNU APL appears to have gained this operator sometime between when you made your comment and now, as this fragment now works as intended!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Dyalog APL? In which case, you should take advantage of the `power` operator as explained by the previous answer (the first piece of code in that answer coming from the book *Mastering Dyalog APL*, p. 416).

Another solution with the same operator would be with matrices:

```
(+.×⍣10)⍨ 2 2⍴1 1 1 0
```

or as a direct function:

```
{⊃(+.×⍣⍵)⍨2 2⍴1 1 1 0} 10
```

If you don't want to use the `power` operator, you may still use matrices (code below tested under GNU APL 1.5):

```
{+.×/⍵⍴⊂2 2⍴1 1 1 0} 10
```

Comment: No, I'm using GNU APL, which is an APL2 language that adheres pretty close to the standard. It's the only APL I can run on the Mac that seems to be supported on an ongoing basis. Dyalog makes me want to buy a RaspberryPi just so I can have a dedicated APL workstation to tinker with, it's pretty slick.

Comment: Hi, on your Mac you can also run NGN APL which is modern, lightweight and great. Anyway, I own six RPi and it is indeed worth buying one if you want to use Dyalog APL (you will also be able to use freely Mathematica for the very same price). Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I think I've found a way to generate the *sequence* of length N (rather than the Nth number) in a single (albeit not-so pretty line of APL2):

```
+/¨(⊂0 0)⍉¨⊖¨(2/¨⍳N)↑¨⊂P←V∘.!V←⍳1+N←20
```

Like I said: not so pretty.
Let me try to break it down into the idioms:

This is the Pascal Triangle with 20 tiers:

```
P←V∘.!V←⍳1+N←20
```

Then we take the N first upper-left-corner squares:

```
(2/¨⍳N)↑¨⊂P
```

This idiom returns the main diagonal of a matrix:

```
(⊂0 0)⍉
```

But we want the anti-diagonal, so before that we'll use `⊖` to flip all squares.

Last step is just to sum all the anti-diagonals with `+/`.

Comment: The method of using Pascal's Triangle comes from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Use_in_mathematics)

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's in origin 0.
Also: the assignment of P is unnecessary.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with GnuAPL - we get a Domain Error at ⍉ - but finding out why it doesn't work is going to be educational. This is a really neat approach, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but here's a clean solution that's safe for gnu-apl, not using the power operator, and slightly tweaking Lobachevsky's "neg-two take" method:

```
fib ← {{⍵, +/ ¯2↑ ⍵} / ⌽ ⍳⍵}
```

The basic trick is reversing the iota list, since compression reads it in backwards. Sample output:

```
      fib 10
 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
```

Comment: I don't think you can use a monadic function on the operator `/` in gnu apl, at least not in the recent svn version I have.  Ignoring the ⍺ is easy though, `{{⍺⊢⍵,+/¯2↑⍵}/⌽⍳⍵}` should do fine.  You may want to put a `⊃` in front.